# PCB Antenna Design Calculations

Tags: pcb-design, antenna, pcb-antenna

I have read the basics of antenna theory and lectures.

I just want some practical PCB antenna design & its calculations /design considerations so as to understand the design calculations better.

Any PCB antenna design regardless of the frequency of the operation and the size will do.
I searched a lot but unable to find one antenna design which showed me the design calculations and the steps.

Can anyone provide me a detailed example of any PCB antenna design that you have designed or any link which provides me what I am searching for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find some references for microstrip patch antenna design.

Firstly you had to determine target frequency and substrate material. For starter you can use standards like FR-4 substrate material with epsilon_r = 4.3 and 1.6mm thick.
Then you need to calculate patch sizes, you can do it by hand with formulas given in references below or you can use microstrip patch antenna calculator (also given below)

After this easy design steps you can simulate it with simulators (I use CST Studio Suite) to optimize the design parameters

[Most appropriate reference for you](http://linux.students.engr.scu.edu/%7Ebhorwath/presentations/Microstrip%20Patch%20Antenna%20Design.pdf)

[Reference 2](http://irianto.staff.gunadarma.ac.id/Downloads/files/2879/Chapter4.pdf)

[Online Calculator](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/microstrip-patch-antenna-calculator/)

[Trailer Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DhXCdvm-Kl8)

After some practice with these, you can go forward with array antennas or different shaped patch antennas like circle. Note that, other shapes than rectengular patch antennas need more complex calculations to design.

Comment: Thank you very much for the references. I would like to under the PCB trace antenna in addition to the patch antenna too. Could you also provide a simple reference or an example for the PCB trace antenna too?